# kasda modem+ router 5212

Tags: networking, router, bridge-router

I have kasda kb5212 (router + modem) and I'm trying to configure it to only modem but cannot understand how.

I configured  a PPPoE + added a bridge connection and disabled DHCP. 
may be I did something wrong ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: " disabled dhcp" how will your local network dives get an IP address?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why do you want to disable the router function on your device?

From my point of view, if the device provides the router function, you can just connect a hub on the LAN port of this device to expand the number of ports. A hub is cheaper than a router.

If you already have a router, you are still able to connect the WAN port of your router to the LAN port of this device. The only difference is that the device provided by the ISP perform the dial-up of the PPPoE, and your router just need to provide the NAT service. There is no significant performance loss for a home network even if the traffic is NATed twice.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But as I have mentioned above, even you can't disable the router function, you are still able to connect your own router to it to provide more functions. Also, the double NAT will not cause significant performance loss. If this is an enterprise network, I would not suggest performing double NAT.